# Add WHERE clause to just one table on Left Join?

Tags: mysql

I'm joining `Sites` with `History` and selecting the rows that aren't in `History`.

```
$data = mysql_query("
        select * from Sites
        left join History
        on Sites.URL = History.URL
        where History.URL is null
        order by Karma
        ");
```

The problem is that I want to add `WHERE UID = $uid` to table History so I only join rows with said UID.

I want to do something like this:

```
    select * from Sites
    left join History where UID = $uid
    on Sites.URL = History.URL
    where History.URL is null
    order by Karma
```

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this to the `JOIN` clause:

```
select * from Sites
left join History ON UID = $uid
AND Sites.URL = History.URL
where History.URL is null
order by Karma
```

or the `WHERE` clause:

```
select * from Sites
left join History
AND Sites.URL = History.URL
where History.URL is null
and UID = $uid
order by Karma
```

**Note:** You should prefix this with the appropriate table name. I would have but you didn't specify.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this way:

```
select * from Sites s
Where Not Exists
   (Select * From History
    Where URL Is Null  
       And uid = $uid)  
order by Karma
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a `not exists` clause:

```
select * from Sites
where not exists (
  select * from History
  where UID = $uid
  and Sites.URL = History.URL)
order by Karma
```